# Modifying state with promises

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-promise-middleware

## Why do my promises not actually update the state in Redux?

I'm using redux-promise-middleware. When I make a call to my API, it goes through the promise steps of _PENDING and _FULFILLED, but the state is never updated to reflect the changes.

How do I do this properly, so that I actually get my data.

---

Here's a picture of my state:

[image: _PENDING and _FULFILLED state]

As you can see, `isFetched` does not become true after the promise is fulfilled, and `data` is never loading the returned response data into itself.

---

This is my API helper:

```
class UserAPI {

     ...

     async testPhone(user) {
         await axios.post(this.testPhonePath, {
             phone: user.phone
         })
         .then(function(response) {
             return response.data
         })
         .catch(function(error) {
             return error.response.data
         })
     }
}
```

---

My action:

```
import { UserAPI } from '../../constants/api'

const userAPI = new UserAPI()

export const TEST_USER_PHONE = 'TEST_USER_PHONE'

export const testUserPhone = (user) => ({
    type: TEST_USER_PHONE,
    payload: userAPI.testPhone(user)
})
```

---

And my reducer:

```js
import {
    TEST_USER_PHONE
} from './actions'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    testedByPhone: {
        data: [],
        isFetched: false,
        error: {
            on: false,
            message: null
        }
    }
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case '${TEST_USER_PHONE}_PENDING':
            return INITIAL_STATE
        case '${TEST_USER_PHONE}_FULFILLED':
            return { 
                testedByPhone: {
                    data: action.payload,
                    isFetched: true,
                    error: {
                        on: false,
                        message: null
                    }
                }
            }
        case '${TEST_USER_PHONE}_REJECTED':
            return { 
                testedByPhone: {
                    data: [],
                    isFetched: true,
                    error: {
                        on: true,
                        message: action.payload
                    }
                }
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

---

Here's my Store

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware'

import reducers from './reducers'

const middleware = [
    promiseMiddleware()
]

if (__DEV__) {
    const logger = require('redux-logger')

    middleware.push(logger())
}

const enhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

export default createStore(
    reducers,
    undefined,
    enhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)
```

Comment: the function `testPhone` doesn't return anything - is that correct?

Comment: Your `testPhone` function doesn't return anything

Comment: Doesn't it return `response.data` or `error.response.data` depending? I'm confused.

Comment: are you applying the middleware when you create the store?

Comment: @MattAft yeah I believe I am, added store to show

Comment: are you sure redux devtools works with react native? I was reading somewhere it didn't but they mightve updated it

Comment: @MattAft Seems like it's working fine for me - also this dude's tutorial at this time shows a working version of my stuff: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNkTQtRUH-M&t=29m8s

Comment: It seems like in the switch statement you wanted to use new JS templates but actually you used just a standard string. Try replacing ' with \`, so: `'${TEST_USER_PHONE}_PENDING'` to `\`${TEST_USER_PHONE}_PENDING\``

Comment: @Oskar TOTALLY WORKED replacing the ' with a ` god damn it that's the second time new JS stuff has wrecked my workflow. Post as an answer please - niiiiiiiice!

Comment: Cool! Ok, I'm posting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working, it is that you use a standard string instead of JS templates. 
Replace:

```
'${TEST_USER_PHONE}_REJECTED'
```

With:

```
`${TEST_USER_PHONE}_REJECTED`
```

Comment: This is why you shouldn't do drugs before coding. Thanks so much for the answer dude - 10/10.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you wanted to use either

```
testPhone(user) {
    return axios.post(this.testPhonePath, {
        phone: user.phone
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data
    }, function(error) {
        return error.response.data
    });
}
```

or

```
async testPhone(user) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(this.testPhonePath, {
            phone: user.phone
        });
        return response.data
    } catch(error) {
        return error.response.data
    }
}
```

but not that current mix which always returns a promise for `undefined` - it only uses `await` but not `return`.

Comment: Actually, I just tried both of those - and while I think what you're saying makes sense and it was a fundamental misunderstanding of promises/async-await - it didn't update my state still. `isFetched` is still false when fulfilled.

Comment: Hm, I have to admit that I have no idea of redux :-/